# Using .text() to select a class but having issues with spaces within the html

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('li.' + $(this).text()).toggle(true);
```

This code is used to take from a subnav below.

```
<div class="subNav">
        <ul>
     <li class="button">sun protective clothing</li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

These are products that will be visible.

```
<div class="sun-protective-clothing"></div>
```

Comment: you're want to pick all the .button li's and change their class? please specify what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @Buildingbrick:Although there is merit that it's "easy to do" or a quick hack, but are you sure you want to go with this approach? A change in your content could render the page useless, or if someone edits the page without realizing that it's tied up to a CSS class by the same name. I suggest storing the class name as a data-* attribute: `<li class="button" data-className="sun-protective-clothing">Sun Protective Clothing</li>` and you could just say `$('li.'+$(this).data('className')).toggle(true);` You'll free up the coupling between the actual content and the class name

Comment: @Nupul: I absolutely agree with the data- attribute approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace the spaces with dashes. Try

```
$('li.' + $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-")).toggle(true);
```

Comment: This will only replace the first space.  You must use a RegEx (Regular Expression).

Answer (score 2):

You must use JavaScript's replace() function to replace all spaces with dashes.  Note using `replace(" ", "-")` like this will only replace the first instance of a space in the string.  you must use a RegEx with the global search to replace all instances; such as `/ /g`

```
$('li.' + $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-")).toggle(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend no using the text inside the li and do something like this:

```
<div class="subNav">
    <ul>
 <li class="button" target="sun-protective-clothing">sun protective clothing</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and:

```
$('.' + $(this).attr("target")).toggle(true);
```

This way you can put whatever you want inside the li, and not have it affect your logic.

Comment: or maybe rel instead of target? `<li class="button" rel="sun-protective-clothing">sun protective clothing</li>`, `$('.' + $(this).attr("rel")).toggle(true);`